# $L^{1} \cap L^{\infty}$ is dense is in $L^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lp-spaces

Why is $L^{1} \cap L^{\infty}$ dense is in $L^{p}$?

My work:
i use the $$\Vert f \Vert_{p} \leq \Vert f \Vert^{1/p}_{1} \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}^{1-1/p}.$$

Comment: How did you define $L^p$ spaces? If you did it via taking the closure of simple functions under the $L^p$ norm, you can just argue that each space contains all of the simple functions and is therefore dense in any other $L^q$ space.

Answer (score 2):

Simple functions are dense in $L^p$ (by exactly the same argument that they are dense in $L^1$). These simple functions can always be taken to be bounded. In a $\sigma$-finite measure space, they can also be taken to have finite measure support. A bounded, measurable function with finite measure support is easily seen to be in $L^1 \cap L^\infty$.

Reference: Royden and Fitzpatrick, Chapter 18.